# How do I get rid of unnecessary properties from the object in typescript

Tags: typescript

If I have an entity interface:

```
interface UserEntity {
name: string;
surname: string;
password: string;
...etc
createdAt: Date;
updatedAt: Date;
}
```

And I don't want to give a user some extra data such as createdAt or his password back
I simply create another interface, for example:

```
interface UserData extends Omit<UserEntity, 'password' | 'createdAt'> {
}
```

Then when I get an entity with UserEntity type is there a simple way in typescript to cast from UserEntity to UserData(basically to slice these extra props in typescript)? I know in JS I could write a function based on `Object.keys()` and `slice()` method.

Comment: You can't "slice" properties in a cast, a cast is only important for the ts compiler.

Comment: Oh, I got it, thanks